# Tensorflow object detection :how to calculate distance between bounding box and specified area in the frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, tensorflow-datasets

I am capturing my video using CV2 and defining the Region of interest in the video frame

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
image_np = cap.read()    
pts = np.array([[57,69], [215,65], [270,476], [3,476]], np.int32)
cv2.polylines(image_np,[pts], isClosed = True, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
```

after defining the above region on interest, whenever my object detection model detect a object with boxes and once it enters the defined region I need to give an alert. how I can go with this?
below is the function from tensorflow object detction

```
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = np.array(Image.open(image_path))
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)

  display(Image.fromarray(image_np))
```

Comment: your python factorial function's `return` statement is **inside** the `while` loop, I don't think that's intentional. If that loop never executes, that function will never return any valid value - it'll just return `None`

Comment: as a side note, consider not using nested functions (definitions) in C unless you intend to not make the code portable. Nested functions are not standard C.

Answer (score 1):

Your `factorial`'s `return` is overindented, so nothing is returned when `n` is `0`. Your C code is wrong too, using a `for` "conditional" of `i=n1`, which would still be wrong even if it were `i == n1`, so it remains wrong in the Python. Neither block of code would work.

Also note: When translating simple C `for` loops over integers to Python, use a Python `for` loop over a `range`, don't implement it as a Python `while` loop.